# React js Error: Uncaught Error: [BrowserRouter] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I'm new on React and I'm facing the error "Uncaught Error: [BrowserRouter] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>".

I'm trying to do a private route to avoid users to land on the dashboard without being loged on.

PrivateRoute.js

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth()

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to='/login' replace />} />
      }}
    ></Route>
  )
}
```

App.js

```
 function App() 
  return( 
        <Container 
        className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" 
        style={{minHeight: "100vh"}}
        >
          <div className="w-100 " style={{ maxWidth: '400px'}}>
            <Router>
              <AuthProvider>
                <Routes>
                  <Route element={<PrivateRoute/>} >
                      <Routes>
                        <Route   path='/' element= {<Dashboard />}/>
                      </Routes>
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />}/>
                  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}/>
                </Routes>
              </AuthProvider>
            </Router>
          </div>
        </Container>
  ) 
}
```

I don't know what to do and can't find info about this specific problem, please explain me like I'm 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you render any `BrowserRouter` component, but do see issue with your `PrivateRoute` component. You are using it as a layout component but then render neither any passed `children` or an `Outlet` for nested routes. There is also no `component` prop passed to it, so `Component` results in being undefined. The `Route` component also doesn't take a `render` prop function in RRDv6. Since you are wrapping and rendering another `Routes` component I'll assume you want to render the `children` prop. Conditionally render the `children` prop or the `Navigate` component.

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth()

  return currentUser ? children : <Navigate to='/login' replace />;
}
```

Use the `PrivateRoute` to wrap the children `Routes` and routes.

```
<Router>
  <AuthProvider>
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="*"
        element={(
          <PrivateRoute>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<Dashboard />} />
            </Routes>
          </PrivateRoute>
        )} 
      />
      <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  </AuthProvider>
</Router>
```

[image: Edit react-js-error-uncaught-error-browserrouter-is-not-a-route-component-all]

The `Router` (*I'm assuming this is one of the higher-level routers, i.e. `BrowserRouter`... if you've another router elsewhere in your app, remove it as you need only one router for the entire app*), `Routes`, and `Route` components in `App` should all work now. If you've still issue from here we may need to see more of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I tried your snippet in PrivateRoute.js but now, as I am not rendering, I'm getting "PrivateRoute(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.", how should I render PrivateRoute? I never did something like this before

Comment: @alvesdaniel Oh, I see, you're quite right. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question, after implementing those changes, I'm getting "No routes matched location "/" ", am I missing something?

Comment: @alvesdaniel Add a path to the route rendering the auth wrapper so it can match `"/"` any other sub-routes.